# Indefinite integration using substitution

Tags: integration

Evaluate

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b+x)}} \, dx $ where $(a + b) > 0$

By letting $u = x + \frac{b-a}{2}$ and $\alpha = \frac{b+a}{2}$ as hinted by my lecturer I obtained:

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-u^2}}\, du$

I am unsure on where to go from here, or even If I'm going in the right direction.

**Edit 1:**

Using the suggestion by @OnceUponACrinoid $u=\alpha sin(v)$, I obtained:

$\int \frac{cos(v)}{\sqrt{1-sin^2(v)}}\, dv$

I then substituted $t=sin(v)$ and obtained:

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\, dt$ which evaluates to $sin^-1(t)$

I then back substituted and ended up with

$sin^{-1}(\frac{2x+b-a}{b+a}) + c, c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Have you covered derivatives of inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: For inverse tan we have, lecturer briefly touched on inverse sine.

Comment: Try and use the substitution $u=\alpha \sin v$.

Comment: BTW worth noting: your lecturer's hint is really nothing more than completing the square:                 $$(a-x)(b+x)=ab+(a-b)x-x^2=\Bigl(\frac{a+b}2\Bigr)^2-\Bigl(\frac{b-a}2+x\Bigr)^2\ .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Integral you obtained is a 'special Integral'.
$$\int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}} = \sin^{-1}\bigg (\dfrac{u}{a}\bigg) +C$$
I'm writing the proof below.
$$$$
Put $u=a\sin(\theta)$ so that $du=a\cos(\theta)d\theta$
$$\Longrightarrow\int \dfrac{du}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}} = \int \dfrac{a\cos(\theta)}{a\cos(\theta)} =\int d\theta = \theta+C$$ Now, since $u=a\sin(\theta), \dfrac{u}{a} = \sin(\theta)\Rightarrow \theta = \sin^{-1}\bigg (\dfrac{u}{a}\bigg )$
$$\Longrightarrow \theta + C=\sin^{-1}\bigg (\dfrac{u}{a}\bigg )+C $$

Answer (score 0):

Use $$ u = \alpha sin v $$
Then use $$ sin^2 v + cos^2 v =1 $$
Then evaluate $ \int \frac{cos v}{ |cos v|} dv$